# onscroll top once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I edit this to run only once after user scroll up:

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (currentScroll < previousScroll){
           alert('up');
       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}()); //run this anonymous function immediately
```

Comment: do you mean run only once ???

Comment: What would you want to do instead of the alert statement there.? Would you like to find somewhere else whether the user is scrolling up ?

Comment: this code alert every time user scroll up i want it to alert the user in the first time he scroll only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the user to be notified only once, then you could just use a boolean to keep track whether the notice is done.

```
(function () {
var previousScroll = 0;
var isAlerted = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if(isAlerted) return;                    
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (currentScroll < previousScroll){
       console.log('up');
       isAlerted = true;
   }
   previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
})();​
```

Also note the change in the last line. Use the self-executing anonymous function properly as

```
(function(){})();
```

Comment: thx it work , but not work when i change  console.log('up'); to my function

Comment: the same code 
work here http://on.fb.me/HqhlZu
not work here  http://on.fb.me/HmIThR

Comment: i think the problem that facebook app disable scrolling :] in page tab view , i don't know how to fix this :S